# Ajax problem on node edit page trigger whole submit

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I'm facing a very strange problem on one website.

First of all with the module `media` (I'm using the last version of the module). When click on "`Remove`" an image, an ajax request is triggered and seems to go through the entire form submit, displays a message above the field but doesn't remove the image.

If I click on "`Remove`" again then it works normally.

Now when I click on a "`Add more`" button like for a multiple `field_collection`, it works fine the first time for the field I click. If I click on an other multiple field (an other `field_collection`) then nothing happens. I don't know if both problems are related.

When I look into the network, I see Ajax queries with all the datas (some differences like the form token), the response is just not the same.

I'm on jQuery 1.4.4 on admin pages and using the Shiny theme. Drupal is 7.41 and hosted on NGINX 1.6.2-5

I've looked into all the "`form_alter`" I had, to see if something got altered. I even deactivated all my custom modules, but the problem is still there.

Any clue would help :-)

Comment: Is there anything in DB logs? Anything in console?

Comment: Nothing in dblog, in console I see the ajax query with status 200 and a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the contrib module `admin_language` not handeling properly the ajax callback url on node edit page.

I had to add these url to be included in the config "Use administration language on only the listed pages." :

```
system/ajax
media/ajax
media/ajax/*
media/*/ajax
```